# Is there a way to resolve a tort discovered after a divorce is finalized?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, marriage

Say divorce procedings have been finalized and there is shared custody of the child. If it is found that one of the partners has been unfaithful, can the other then sue for full custody of the child or any financial penalties?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, where is the tort? Infidelity is not a tort.

US divorce is no fault - infidelity of either or both partners is irrelevant to the divorce settlement or the custody arrangements of any children.

Comment: Yes. Plus, even if faults were relevant for divorce, they would not necessarily be relevant for custody arrangements.